Overpass API & Road Lanes
I've written a script in Python that, given a lat/long, generates a geojson with the roads edges, pedestrian crosses and lanes. It looks like this:
def fetch_intersection_data(lat, lon, radius: int = 20):
    """
    Fetch intersection data from OpenStreetMap using Overpass API and convert to GeoJSON.
    
    :param lat: Latitude of the center of the intersection
    :param lon: Longitude of the center of the intersection
    :param radius: Radius around the point to search (in meters)
    :return: GeoJSON data as a dictionary
    """
    overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
    overpass_query = f"""
                [out:json];
                (
                way["highway"](around:{radius},{lat},{lon});
                node["highway"="crossing"](around:{radius},{lat},{lon});
                way["lanes"](around:{radius},{lat},{lon});
                way["lanes:forward"](around:{radius},{lat},{lon});
                way["lanes:backward"](around:{radius},{lat},{lon});
                );
                out geom;
    """
    print(overpass_query)
    response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': overpass_query})
    osm_data = response.json()

    with open('raw_data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(osm_data, f)

    try:
        features = []

        for element in osm_data['elements']:
                feature = {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": element.get('tags', {}),
                    "geometry": None
                }
                
                if element['type'] == 'way':
                    if 'geometry' in element:
                        feature['geometry'] = {
                            "type": "LineString",
                            "coordinates": [[point['lon'], point['lat']] for point in element['geometry']]
                        }
                    feature['properties']['id'] = element['id']

                elif element['type'] == 'node':
                    feature['geometry'] = {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [element['lon'], element['lat']]
                    }
                    feature['properties']['id'] = element['id']
                
                if feature['geometry']:
                    features.append(feature)
            
        geojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": features}
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return geojson

So far so good: it's doing almost everything I need. For instance, this is how the geojson looks when I plot it on geojson.io:

Now, what it is missing is the lanes within the road. What I mean by that is that what I'd like to be able to fetch the geometries/coordinates to plot something like this (in red):

The JSON file returned by the API doesn't seem to have the lanes coordinates. I'm not sure if my query is missing something or if this information is not available.
Any thoughts?

Lanes in OSM don't have their own coordinates. Lanes are specified via attributes of the corresponding highway. They mostly consist of a lanes count and a direction (relative to the direction of the way they belong to), with a few other attributes that are rarely present. So you have to estimate their positions yourself.
